# UICollectionView delegate method didSelectItemAt not called on iOS 11

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, ios11

Ive recently updated to xcode beta 9 and iOS beta 6 and am trying to run an application where I am using RGPageViewController (https://github.com/eRGoon/RGPageViewController) but all of a sudden the didSelectItemAt delegate method is not being called, any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is a very poor quality question. It's not clear. And also It's not obvious whether you have made any effort.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set tabbarstyle to solid. It will work for you let me know if you still have any issue.

override var tabbarStyle: RGTabbarStyle {
        return .solid
    }